# WL and WLS textformatting

Tags: formatting, scripting

I am really happy with the new wls (Wolfram Language Script) files. I somewhat abuse the file format, I use them instead of the regular Notebook files. The advantage is that they do not store the output. Therefore they are quick to save (you can even enable auto-save) and using git started to make sense. But then... I started to add some text-cells, which is fine for non-formatted text, but when using more advanced formatting (like Subscript) it goes wrong.

So to summarize my issue (also see image [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpPVT.png) and [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFxAJ.png)):

1. Create .wls file
2. Add some formatted text in a text-cell $s_{sub}$ (the same also occurs in a code-cell)
3. Close and Re-open file and notice that you now see the non-formatted form `Subscript[s, sub]`

[image: creating a new wls file]
[image: After re-opening the formatting is gone]

I don't think there is a neat solution for this, as this might be expected behavior. However I found it frustrating that I can create a new .wls file containing nice formatting, but once I close and re-open it the formatting is gone.

Comment: Open file -> Ctrl+A -> Ctrl+Shift+N

Comment: That works great! Would it also be possible to set this in the options of the file? So you do not have to do this each time?

Comment: As .wls file do not save options, that's not a good idea. But would it be possible to edit the default settings for wls files?

Comment: Don't have time for a proper answer but you can set `CurrentValue[EvaluationNotebook[],"DefaultScriptStyleDefinitions"]` to a custom file which will inherit from `"Script.nb"` and with custom `NotebookDynamicExpression` which deletes itself after doing this change.

Comment: Also the Ctrl+A->Ctrl+Shift+N method does not work for text cells

Comment: Thanks it works. But could you explain more that why this works? What is this shortcut key for?

Comment: @JakePan, Ctr(or Cmd)+Shift+N is equivalent to Cell -> Convert To -> StandardForm.